# Omniture SiteCatalyst Instances/Search metric and conversion variables

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics

We have a weird reporting inconsistency between two Report Suites in Omniture's SiteCatalyst. Currently we have a conversion variable that is tracking keyword values that are coming from search engines using crossVisitParticipation and channelManager plugins.

When we run the Traffic Source" report that shows "Search Keyword - All" broken down by the conversion variable one report always shows "N/A" values and the the other doesn't. Somehow one report suite is not relating the search engines report to my conversion variable and the other is. Any idea why?

Here are some screenshots:

Report with "N/A"
Link http://i48.tinypic.com/1zwi4b9.png
[image: screenshot 1]

Report with Actual Values
Link http://i46.tinypic.com/egbnmh.png
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: How exactly would one duplicate each of these reports in SiteCatalyst? Are both reports using the same breakdowns? Is the 'Searches' metric you're using the same metric under both reports?

If you can provide information on how you created these reports based on the actual variables and metrics used, we can probably provide a little more information.

Comment: Yes, both reports are using the same metrics; "Searches" metric broken down by a conversion variable (eVar) called "Keyword Stacking". 

I am comparing the exact same report generated from different report suites. When and how would the "Searches" metric be different when running the Search Engines - All report?

Comment: stupid question...are you sure both report suite ids are being popped in s_account on all your page code?

Comment: Not a stupid question at all. I thought the same thing. Yes, that is one of the first things I checked. s_account is populated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before too. I really suggest you just call Omniture client care. So many things in SiteCatalyst are configurable by Omniture, I am sure that it is the way your setup is configured to give this kind of result in your reports.